# Can't Change SSH Daemon's Port Number under CentOS 7

Tags: port, sshd, centos-7

I've upgraded my VPS to CentOS 7 from CentOS 6. Back when I was running CentOS 6, simply changing the port number of the SSH daemon under `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` used to make my remote SSH connection happen with the port number I've designated in that file.

Now that I'm using CentOS 7, the same technique does not apply even though people say on the internet that it should. I change the port number under `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, try to test the connection with the defined port number and the connection gets refused with that port number. I've also tried the old port number which was the default 22 or logging in as root.

I've also made a lengthy chat with my VPS provider resulting in a conclusion that he was not able to resolve the problem unfortunately. He told me to run the command `ssh -v -v root@<my-ip>` on my local computer to show me that my CentOS installation was not looking for the port number under `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Here is the result of that command and others before:

```
~ ❯❯❯ ssh can@<my-ip>                                                                                                       
ssh: connect to host <my-ip> port 22: Connection refused
~ ❯❯❯ ssh can@<my-ip> -p 2135                                                                                               
ssh: connect to host <my-ip> port 2135: Connection refused
~ ❯❯❯ ssh -v -v root@<my-ip>                                                                                                
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/can/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <my-ip> [<my-ip>] port 22.
debug1: connect to address <my-ip> port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host <my-ip> port 22: Connection refused
~ ❯❯❯ ssh -v -v can@<my-ip>                                                                                                 
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/can/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <my-ip> [<my-ip>] port 22.
debug1: connect to address <my-ip> port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host <my-ip> port 22: Connection refused
~ ❯❯❯
```

What should I do to change my port number for remote SSH connections under CentOS 7?

Comment: Try first of all to see which port your daemon is listening on: `ss -lntp | grep ssh`. This will show **whether** it is listening on a port, and **on which port**. Second, you need to check your firewall rules. If you use `iptables`, use `iptables -L -n -v`, and **double,triple,quadruple-check** that your intended port is open.

Comment: allright, it was a firewall issue

Comment: Can you post how you solved it? You should answer your own question. For future readers, it can be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was firewall related. Defining the port number under `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` was successfully making the change but firewall was not letting it.

Therefore I did the following:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service=ssh
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=<my-port-number>/tcp
```